# What's the most efficient way to print all elements of vector in ascending order till it's empty without duplicates?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm supposed to:

1. Print vector elements sorted without repetition.
2. Delete the elements that are printed from vector.
3. Repeat the the previous steps until vector is empty.

But it seems that my code takes more time so, I seek for optimisation. I've tried to do this task with `std::vector` and `std::set`. 

 
Here is my approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n);
    set<int> st;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> v[i];
    }

    while (!v.empty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
            st.insert(v[i]);
        for (auto x : st) {
            cout << x << ' ';
            auto it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
            if (it != v.end())
                v.erase(it);
        }
        st.clear();
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example input is like:

```
7
1 2 3 3 2 4 3
```

Output gonna be like this:

```
1 2 3 4 
2 3 
3
```

Comment: Why not the output is  `1 2 3 4 ; 2 3 4; 3 4; 4` ?? why 4 is ignored??

Comment: @Praveen Because we remove `1 2 3 4` from the vector so the remaining element would be only `2 3 3` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You might use `std::map` instead of `std::vector`/`std::set` to keep track of numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main () {
    map<int, int> m;

    int size;
    std::cin >> size;

    for (int i = 0; i != size; i++) {
        int number;
        std::cin >> number;
        ++m[number];
    }

    while (!m.empty()) {
        for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); /*Empty*/) {
            const auto number = it->first;
            auto& count = it->second;
            std::cout << number << ' ';
            if (--count == 0) {
                it = m.erase(it);
            } else {
                ++it;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Complexity is now `O(n log(n))` instead of `O(n²)` (with lot of internal allocations).

Comment: `std::unordered_map` tends to be much faster than std::map, even with an additional `std::copy` to a vector and `std::sort` at the end. Benchmarking suggested. (And then there are third-party hash tables that are much faster still.)

Comment: @Jarod42 there's a missing semicolon `int number` and use `it != m.end();` instead of `m != m.end();`

Comment: @MohamedMagdy: typos fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::map`

```
auto n = 0;
std::cin >> n;

std::map<int, int> mp;
while (--n >= 0) {
    auto i = 0;
    std::cin >> i;
    mp[i] += 1;
}

while (!mp.empty()) {
    for (auto& it: mp) {
        std::cout << it.first << " ";
        it.second--;
    }

    for (auto it = mp.begin(); it != mp.end(); ++it) {
        if (it->second == 0) mp.erase(it);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

without any erase

```
auto n = 0;
std::cin >> n;

std::map<int, int> mp;
while (--n >= 0) {
    auto i = 0;
    std::cin >> i;
    mp[i] += 1;
}

auto isDone = false;
while (!isDone) {
    isDone = true;
    for (auto& it: mp) {
        if (it.second > 0) std::cout << it.first << " ";
        if (--it.second > 0) isDone = false;
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: But this just printed `1 2 3 4`. `2 3` and `3` in the next two lines are missed.

Comment: `1 2 3 4 ; 2 3 4; 3 4; 4` why not 4... I'll update the answer to get the output..

Comment: You misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Due to it overwriting the elements expected to be deleted, `std::unique` won't be much use for this problem. My solution:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

while (!v.empty())
{
    int last = v.front();
    std::cout << last << " ";
    v.erase(v.begin());

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); /* no-op */)
    {
        if (*it == last)
        {
            ++it;
        }
        else
        {
            last = *it;
            std::cout << last << " ";
            it = v.erase(it);
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

You could probably improve performance further by reversing the sorting of the vector, and then iterating through backwards (since it's cheaper to delete from closer to the back of the vector), but that would complicate the code further, so I'll say "left as an exercise for the reader".

Comment: Even with `reverse_iterator`, complexity is `O(n²)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 true; your answer is more efficient. And since a sort is required at minimum, it won't be beaten on time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `sort` and `vector`.  It uses a second vector to hold the unique items and print them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,3,2,4,3};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::vector<int>::iterator vit;
    while(!v.empty()){
        std::vector<int> printer;
        std::vector<int>::iterator pit;
        vit = v.begin();
        while (vit != v.end()){
            pit = find(printer.begin(), printer.end(), *vit);
            if (pit == printer.end()){
                printer.push_back(*vit);
                vit = v.erase(vit);
            } else {
                ++vit;
            }
        }
        std::copy(printer.begin(), printer.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3
3
```

Comment: You don't improve time complexity of the program.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear (at least to me) exactly what you're talking about when you mention "efficiency". Some people use it to refer solely to computational complexity. Others think primarily in terms of programmer's time, while still others think of overall execution speed, regardless of whether that's obtained via changes in computational complexity, or (for one example) improved locality of reference leading to better cache utilization.

So, with that warning, I'm not sure whether this really improves what you care about or not, but it's how I think I'd do the job anyway:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// preconditions: input range is sorted
template <class BidiIt>
BidiIt partition_unique(BidiIt begin, BidiIt end) {
    auto pivot = end;
    for (auto pos = begin; pos != pivot; ++pos) {
        auto mid = std::next(pos);

        for ( ; mid < pivot && *mid == *pos; ++mid, --pivot)
            ;
        std::rotate(std::next(pos), mid, end);
    }
    return pivot;
}

template <class It>
void show(It b, It e, std::ostream &os) {
    while (b != e) {
        os << *b << ' ';
        ++b;
    }
    os << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> input{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3 };

    std::sort(input.begin(), input.end());

    auto begin = input.begin();

    auto pos = begin;
    while ((pos = partition_unique(begin, input.end())) != input.end()) {
        show(begin, pos, std::cout);
        begin = pos;
    }
    show(begin, input.end(), std::cout);
}
```

I'm not really sure it's possible to improve the computational complexity much over what this does (but it might be--I haven't thought about it enough to be sure one way or the other). Compared to some versions I see posted already, there's a decent chance this will improve overall speed (e.g., since it just moves things around inside the same vector, it's likely to get better locality than those that copy data from one vector to another.

Answer (score 0):

> The code is in java but the idea remains the same.

- At first, I sort the array. Now, the idea is to create buckets.
- This means that each line of sorted elements is like a bucket. So, find the count of each element. Now, put that `element` into `each bucket`, `count` number of times. If it so happens that bucket size is less, create a new bucket and add the current element to it.
- In the end, print all buckets.
- Time Complexity is `O(nlog(n))` for sorting and `O(n)` for the buckets since you have to visit each and every element to print it. So, it's `O(nlog(n)) + O(n) = O(nlog(n))` asymptotically.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class GFG {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr1 = {1,2,3,3,2,4,3};
        int[] arr2 = {45,98,65,32,65,74865};
        int[] arr3 = {100,100,100,100,100};
        int[] arr4 = {100,200,300,400,500};
        printSeries(compute(arr1,arr1.length));
        printSeries(compute(arr2,arr2.length));
        printSeries(compute(arr3,arr3.length));
        printSeries(compute(arr4,arr4.length));
    }

    private static void printSeries(List<List<Integer>> res){
        int size = res.size();
        for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
            System.out.println(res.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> compute(int[] arr,int N){
        List<List<Integer>> buckets = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int bucket_size = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
            int last_index = i;

            if(bucket_size > 0){
                buckets.get(0).add(arr[i]);
            }else{
                buckets.add(newBucket(arr[i]));
                bucket_size++;
            }

            for(int j=i+1;j<N;++j){
                if(arr[i] != arr[j]) break;

                if(j-i < bucket_size){
                    buckets.get(j-i).add(arr[i]);
                }else{
                    buckets.add(newBucket(arr[i]));
                    bucket_size++;
                }

                last_index = j;
            }

            i = last_index;   
        }

        return buckets;
    }

    private static List<Integer> newBucket(int value){
        List<Integer> new_bucket = new ArrayList<>();
        new_bucket.add(value);
        return new_bucket;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3]
[3]

[32, 45, 65, 98, 74865]
[65]

[100]
[100]
[100]
[100]
[100]

[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3f06693a74193e5

The key idea:

1. sort vector
2. print by iterating. just print a value if it differs from last printed
3. remove unique elements. i have done this with what i called inverse_unique. the std library comes with an algorithm called unique, which will remove all duplicates. i inverted this so that it will just keep all dublicates.

so we have no memory allocation at all. i cant see how one could make the algorithm more efficient. we are just doing the bare minimum and its exactly done the way a human thinks about.

i tested it with several combinations. hope its bug free ;-P

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<class ForwardIt>
ForwardIt inverse_unique(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    if (first == last)
        return last;

    auto one_ahead = first+1; 
    auto dst = first;

    while(one_ahead != last)
    {
        if(*first == *one_ahead)
        {
            *dst = std::move(*first);
            ++dst;
        }
        ++first;
        ++one_ahead;
    }

    return dst;
}

void print_unique(std::vector<int> const& v)
{
    if(v.empty()) return;

    // print first
    std::cout << v[0] << ' ';
    auto last_printed = v.cbegin();            

    // print others
    for(auto it = std::next(std::cbegin(v)); it != std::cend(v); ++it)
    {
        if(*it != *last_printed)
        {
            std::cout << *it << ' ';
            last_printed = it;            
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void remove_uniques(std::vector<int> & v)
{
    auto new_end = inverse_unique(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    v.erase(new_end, v.end()); 
}

int main () 
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3};
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));

    while (!v.empty()) 
    {
        print_unique(v);
        remove_uniques(v);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit: updated inverse_unique function. should be easy to understand now.**

Answer (score 0):

Half baked at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c45df1591d967075

Slightly modified counting sort.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,3,2,4,3};
  std::map<int, int> map;

  for (auto x : v)
    ++map[x];

  while(map.size()) {
    for(auto pair = map.begin(); pair != map.end(); ) {
      std::cout << pair->first << ' ';
      if (!--pair->second)
        pair = map.erase(pair);
      else
        ++pair;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```